# Which one is correct: The bird was standing on the table, from where/which it flew toward me all of a sudden

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositional-phrases

I would like to know whether I should use "from where" or "from which" in the following sentence:

The bird was standing on the table, from where/from which it flew toward me.

Comment: Both relative pronouns are valid in such contexts, but [***from which** is far more common than **from where***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+place+from+where+it%2Cthe+place+from+which+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20place%20from%20where%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20place%20from%20which%20it%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I'd certainly choose 'where' here (the visualisation being largely locative) unless this was an experiment in which the bird had been flying between various objects provided (when the _type_ of object could be highlighted).

Comment: "The bird was standing on my table, from which it flew onto the sofa" I don't know if I am right, but in this sentence the object is highlighted so I think maybe from which is better in this case?

Comment: Also possible, “The bird was standing on my table. From there, it flew onto the sofa.”

Comment: @Jim Yes, it's definitely possible. But I prefer to think of my table as an object in this case, as the bird was moving from one object to another, instead of a location. From which=from it & From where= from there

The bird was standing on my table, from which it flew onto the sofa= The bird was standing on my table. And then it flew onto the sofa from it. 

The bird was standing on my table, from where it flew onto the sofa= The bird was stand on my table. And then it flew onto the sofa from there.

Comment: @ChienTeLu -No problem.  I, personally, think of those as locations more than things in this kind of situation, but as others have said, there’s no one right answer here.

Comment: @Jim Also this: The man jumped onto the barrel, from which he then jumped upon me. Again, the location is not the point but the object the man jumped on. 

On the other hand, if we need to use "from where", it's more about the transition of location, especially when we think of it in two dimensions. 

For example, the man jumped onto the barrel, from where he rushed into my room and disappeared. Here, from whcih is not used as the object is not highlighted.

Comment: Yes. But also, “where is the bird? He’s on the table, on the sofa, on the desk...”

Comment: @Jim I agreed with you after reading your explanation. How about this sentence: The man was standing on the bridge, from where he jumped into the river and killed himself.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is wrong. The choice is stylistic, not grammatical.

*whence* would be an archaic alternative, that is similarly being deprecated like *whom*.

There is no need to use a relative clause at all, because there is no selection to make. If you are merely expressing a sequence of events, *then* or *before* can order the events in the temporal domain, so that the tempus can remain constant. In fact, a temporal marker like *before* is almost required to correlate different tempi.

> The bird stood on the table. Then it flew towards me.
>
> The bird was standing on the table, before it flew towards me.

*before* also has the advantage that it historically relates with *front*, *pre-* etc. So it expresses immediacy in the local domain as well, cp. *before we go in*.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Actually I personally prefer from where to from which. The alternative you just mentioned, whence, actually refers to "from where". The point is that from which refers to the desk itself, which I personally think is a little bit weird as the bird didn't fly directly out of the desk, while from where indicates the location, in this case, "from on the desk"